# Umbraco RelationService.GetByParentId(memberId) slow. Fires two queries per item

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm currently trying to get all relation items for one parent by calling:

```
var items = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.RelationService.GetByParentId(members.GetCurrentMemberId()).ToArray();
```

It all works fine. Except when I look at the MiniProfiler, I can see it's firing off two queries per item, which is causing some major performance issues with larger amounts of items.
[image: MiniProfiler]

I looked at the UmbracoCMS code and I found this piece of code:

```
protected override IEnumerable<IRelation> PerformGetByQuery(IQuery<IRelation> query)
{
    var sqlClause = GetBaseQuery(false);
    var translator = new SqlTranslator<IRelation>(sqlClause, query);
    var sql = translator.Translate();

    var dtos = Database.Fetch<RelationDto>(sql);

    foreach (var dto in dtos)
    {
        yield return Get(dto.Id);
    }
}
```

The foreach on the `dtos` is sending a query for each `MoveNext()` to the `umbracoRelationType` table. The `Get()` method actually queries the individual item from the `umbracoRelation` table.
I think it's supposed to utilize the cache there, but evidently it's not.

Anyway. How do I improve performance here? Can I somehow get to the content in just a single query without completely bypassing Umbraco?

I'm using Umbraco 7.2.6

Comment: Maybe ask the same question on http://our.umbraco.org - or, ultimately, create an issue on http://issues.umbraco.org/ ? I know that won't automagically solve your problem, but maybe getting more eyes on it can get you closer :-)

Comment: Thanks. I submitted the issue here: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-6801

Comment: Your MiniProfiler profile screenshot starts at 40s! I'm more interested in what happens in that time rather than during the snippet you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting the parent node or Id - and then using

```
ApplicationContext.Services.RelationService.GetById(parent.Id)
```

as it suffers from less database queries.